# can't pause exoplayer in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, exoplayer

I'm developing a palyer app using `jetpack compose` and I want to play/pause programatically.
here is my code:

```
val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()
    .also { exoPlayer ->
        val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
            .setUri("www.mp4")
            .build()
        exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
        exoPlayer.prepare()
        exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
    }
DisposableEffect(
    key1 = AndroidView(
        factory = {
            StyledPlayerView(context).apply {
            hideController()
            useController = false
            player = exoPlayer
            exoPlayer.videoScalingMode = C.VIDEO_SCALING_MODE_DEFAULT
            exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
                }
            }
        ),
        effect = {
            onDispose { exoPlayer.release() }
          }
      )
```

also I created a `LaunchedEffect` which makes the player `stop` after 5 seconds
here is my `LaunchedEffect`:

```
LaunchedEffect(
    key1 = shouldShowValidator,
    block = {
        if (shouldShowValidator) {
            exoPlayer.playWhenReady = false
            exoPlayer.pause()
        }
    }
)
```

I expect to `pause` the player but i dont get that!
what is the problem ?

Comment: What's setting shouldShowValidator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is you should use `Dispatchers.Main` for pausing the player

```
    LaunchedEffect(
        key1 = shouldShowValidator,
        block = {
            if (shouldShowValidator) {
                withContext(
                    context = Dispatchers.Main,
                    block = {
                        exoPlayer.playWhenReady = false
                        exoPlayer.pause()
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: Maybe you can solve it by using LifecycleEventObserver - - this guy described the solution: https://itnext.io/how-to-make-exoplayer-lifecycle-aware-in-jetpack-compose-6d4084b122e3

Answer (score 1):

I managed to pause the video after `5` seconds using the following code

```
val context = LocalContext.current
val exoPlayer = remember {
    ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().apply {
        setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri("<Enter video url>"))
        prepare()
        playWhenReady = true
    }
}

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        delay(5000)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            exoPlayer.playWhenReady = false
            Toast.makeText(context, "Paused", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
DisposableEffect(
    key1 = AndroidView(
        factory = {
            StyledPlayerView(context).apply {
                player = exoPlayer
                layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
            }
        }, modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
            .padding(8.dp)
    )
) {
    onDispose {
        exoPlayer.release()
    }
}
```

PS: `shouldShowValidator` could be the reason the video is not being paused in your case.